# JSON Schema definition from another common Schema

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I'm trying to make a commonTypes.json schema that will be referenced for a specific pattern type that will be used on almost all other API's

So if I have

```
"type": "object",
"properties": {
    "foo": {
         "$ref": "#/definitions/fooString"
    }
},
```

and then have a definitions section with fooString within it, it works fine. However when I try

```
"type": "object",
"properties": {
    "foo": {
         "$ref": "../common/commonTypes.json#/definitions/fooString"
    }
},
```

it doesn't work, I've even tried putting the full filepath which also doesnt work. When looking for solutions online, I think I need to use a "id" but this has to be a absolute path, which we cant really use on the filesystem we are using.

Anyone ideas on how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

What implementation are you using?

In general, you need to make sure that the target of your `$ref` is known to the implementation before it tries to load your main schema (that contains the `$ref`).  Exactly how this works is implementation-specific.

`id` (draft-04) or `$id` (draft-06 and later) is used to identify schemas.  It does not have to be a file path (or a URL at all- it can be a `urn:` or `tag:` URI if you don't care about it being network-accessible).

So if you can give your target an `id`/`$id` and ensure that the implementation understands it first, then you should be able to `$ref` that `id` in your main schema.